# How to create a json from the json as function

Tags: python, json

Need to create a `function` to extract values from the json. after that i need to parse the so many similar type of json and save in to file.

json is below

```
    j = '''{ 
   "action": "post",
    "status": "completed",
    "result": {
    "country": "usa",
    "is_allow": 'true',
    "advance details": {
    "value": 'true'
    }
    }
    }'''
```

convert to json

```
k = eval(json.dumps(m))
```

`{'action': 'post',
 'status': 'completed',
 'result': {'country': 'usa',
  'is_allow': 'true',
  'advance details': {'value': 'true'}}}`

Expected out

`{'is_allow': 'true','value': 'true'}`

pseudo code

Disclaimer : please don't do `m['result']['is_allow']` because i need as function to pass so many json

Comment: What do you mean, the best option is to do `m['result']['is_allow']` and why do you eval? you `json.loads`

Comment: can you help me in write a fuction? so that i can pass simiar kind of keys

Comment: i dont get what do you mean, `m['result']['is_allow']` is what you are searching, just change the keys when you need to, it is the function of  `__getitem__`

Comment: This makes no sense. You can't have JSON as a function. You shouldn't be using `eval`. Do you mean that you want a function that can parse arbitrary JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with json in python, it should be deserialized into a python object, like a dict, or list; it's weird think to create a function that is 'generic' to any key you want to get, it's just the `__getitem__` of `dict`, if you think to export thing into function, be more specific like this:

```py
def get_is_allow_and_value(my_data):
    result = {}
    result['is_allow'] = my_data['result']['is_allow']
    result['value'] = my_data['result']['advance details']['value']
    return result
```

Also don't use `eval` you can simple use `json.loads` for this